# How do I import a python project that is not available in package manager in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have created a simple `python` project in PyCharm. It only has one `python` file as of now. I'd like to import [this](https://github.com/uArm-Developer/pyuf) `github` project in my newly created `python` project so that I can reference some of its libraries and add something in my `python` file. How do I do this in `PyCharm`? I tried to go to `Python Interpreter` and adding this github project after cloning it but it didn't work.

Comment: You have to install it. You can probably do that using `pip install [package]` if it's listed on pie.

Comment: @Zizouz212: No it's not listed on `PyPi`

Comment: In that case, you should be able to build from source. You'd have to download the source, open up terminal or command prompt, change your working directory to the downloaded folder, and run `python setup.py install` to install from source. There may be a way from PyCharm, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok. I did that and it got installed in `site-packages`. Now how do I import that in `PyCharm`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special. Just import it like you would with something like sys or os.

Comment: That worked :) Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Feel free to write it as an answer and mark your own as accepted if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did

1. I used terminal to go to the `cloned` project from github.
2. This folder had a `setup.py`.
3. I then did python3 setup.py install
4. It then installed it to my `site-packages` folder where my `python3` installation was
5. Then I opened `Pycharm` and clicked on `Preferences` >> `Python Interpreter` then in the list I saw the installed `github` project